# REVOKE in SNOWFLAKE

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Team,
I am trying to revoke :FUTURE PROCEDURE" grant on a role in Snowflake.

Below code does not work, any idea how to do this?

```
REVOKE USAGE ON FUTURE PROCEDURE IN SCHEMA TEST_TEST.TEST_D FROM ROLE TEST_TESTING_D;
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to revoke this permission, changed to `ON FUTURE PROCEDURES` (plural):

```
CREATE DATABASE TEST_TEST;
CREATE SCHEMA TEST_D;
CREATE ROLE TEST_TESTING_D;

GRANT USAGE ON FUTURE PROCEDURES IN SCHEMA TEST_TEST.TEST_D 
TO ROLE TEST_TESTING_D;


REVOKE USAGE ON FUTURE PROCEDURES IN SCHEMA TEST_TEST.TEST_D 
FROM ROLE TEST_TESTING_D;
```